# Laravel + jQuery AJAX file upload?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file, laravel-5

I've been trying to get this done for over a week now and nothing seems to work. Users are supposed to be able to upload a file to the server with a name, but somehow AJAX is not sending anything.

This is the form where a user uploads the file:

```
        <div class="data-attachment" data-id="">
            <div class="new-attachment">
            <form id="form-attachment" name="newAttachment">
                <input type="text" class="attachment-name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                <input id="file" type="file" name="file" class="attachment-name">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add attachment" id="submit">
            </form>                    
            </div>
            <button class="btn-del">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
```

This is the function being called upon submission of the form:

```
        $('#form-attachment').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            form = document.forms.namedItem('newAttachment');
            formData = new FormData(form);
            reader = new FileReader();

            // data = {
            //     'name': formData.get('name'),
            //     'file': reader.readAsText($('#file')[0].files[0], 'UTF-8'),
            //     'task': $('#holder').data('id')
            // };

            console.log(formData.get('file'));

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/ajax/tasks/attachments/add',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                    // window.location.reload();
                },
                error: function (xhr, response, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        });
```

This is the PHP code that recieves the form:

```
/**
 * @param Req $request
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function addAttachment(Req $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()
        && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'
        && $request->exists('file')
        && $request->exists('name')
        && $request->exists('task')
        && Auth::user()->hasRight('projects.tasks.attachments.add')
    ) {
        $oTask = Task::find($_POST['task']);
            if ($oTask) {

                Request::file('file')->store(
                    '/'.$oTask->project->id, 'local'
                );
                $oTask->attachments()->create([
                    'name' => $request->input('name'),
                    'file' => $request->file('file')
                ]);

                $oTask->project->logs()->save(
                    new Log(['description' => 'User ' . Auth::user()->nameFormatter() . ' added attachment ' . $_POST['name'] . ' to task ' . $oTask->name . ' in project ' . $oTask->project->name])
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

The files serve as attachments to tasks, hence the 'task' index.
I've searched through multiple similar questions and tried to apply codes from the answers but nothing seems to work. Any help or a point to the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: does the first condition returns false?

Comment: If I  `echo $request;` in function `addAttachment()` I get the fully submitted form without hassle, however if I specifically call `$request->file('file');` it says null

Comment: @Beginner no, both `$request->ajax()` as well as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` return true

Comment: did you try dump native $_FILES just try to see it really been submitted the file

Comment: @Beginner just did, returns empty

Comment: Just found out that for some reason AJAX misreads the given file and reads the curly brackets in the encoding as an array and sets it as a parameter to the request

Answer (score 0):

I see it didnt submit the file because your form is locking of [`enctype="multipart/form-data"`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

```
    <div class="data-attachment" data-id="">
        <div class="new-attachment">
        <form id="form-attachment" name="newAttachment" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" class="attachment-name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            <input id="file" type="file" name="file" class="attachment-name">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add attachment" id="submit">
        </form>                    
        </div>
        <button class="btn-del">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
```

also try just appending into your formData

```
 if ($("#file")[0].files > 0) {
     var file = $("#file")[0].files[0];
     formData.append("file", file, file.name);
 }
```

Comment: Added it, I still get the file from echoing `$request` however after dumping either `$request->input('file')`, `$request->file('file')` or `$_FILES` like you said I'm still getting null

Comment: Apparently AJAX misreads the file encoding and sees the curly brackets as an array, setting said 'array' as a parameter to the request